# Vue JS Dynamic data and model in form input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding

I'm trying to create a form where users edit their comments. The input should display the current value of the comment (which is dynamic data coming from a v-for), but I also need to bind the value to a model so that I may send it with my patch request.

Currently the form looks like this

```
<p @click="editing = true">
     Edit comment
</p>
<form v-if="editing" @submit.prevent="editComment(comment._id)">
   <input type="text" v-model="comment.message"/>
   <button type="submit">
     Edit Comment
   </button>
 </form>
```

Would there be any way to combine the v-model and :value binding? Or a way to bind the model value aswell and setting the name of the data?

Comment: *Would there be any way to combine the `v-model` and `:value` binding?* ...well [`v-model` does bind `value` attribute](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming every comment is rendered within it's own comment, this would be an approach you can use (not tested):

Parent component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Comment 
      v-for="comment in comments"
      :key="comment._id"
      :comment="comment"
      @on-update="onUpdateComment"
    />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        comments: [] // Could be also a computed property, or you populate the array somewhere in this component
      }
    },

    methods: {
      onUpdateComment({ commentId, value }) {
        // Perform update
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Child component (Comment):

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ comment.message }}

    <p @click="onClickEdit">
        Edit comment
    </p>

    <form v-if="editing" @submit.prevent="editComment">
      <input type="text" :value="updatedCommentMessage"/>

      <button type="submit">
        Edit Comment
      </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      comment: {
        type: Object
      }
    },

    data () {
      return {
        editing: false,
        updatedCommentMessage: ''
      }
    }

    methods: {
      onClickEdit () {
        this.editing = true
        this.updatedCommentMessage = this.comment.message
      },

      editComment () {
        this.$emit('on-update', { commentId: this.comment.id, value: this.updatedCommentMessage})
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The benefit of storing the message bound to the input in it's own variable is, that you easily can cancel the action, by just resetting the `updatedCommentMessage` variable.

Comment: This returns error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'message')" when the updatedCommentMessage is set. However I don't see how the comment prop will be able to access the dynamic data

Comment: I've updated my post, so you better see what I mean. The parent component holds the actual comments, which gets passed down to the child component. If any update occurs, the parent component needs to get notified

Comment: I see. This was not the structure I've been doing it in though. I have been having the Post and the Comments in the same component, but I guess splitting them up will be the best way to make this action work

Comment: I would suggest to do so. It's way easier to maintain. However, it should also work with having everything in the same component. It's just a bit trickier, because you need to track, which comment currently gets updated (and therefore you need take care of setting and resetting values)